# Gulp with Laravel Elixir throws events.js:141 unhandled 'error' event

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

Since yesterday, gulp throws unhandled error event:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PhpStorm 10.0.1\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program >Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\..\..\..\..\..\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js --color -->gulpfile "d:\..\..\..\gulpfile.js" default
[11:41:02] Using gulpfile d:\..\..\..\gulpfile.js
[11:41:02] Starting 'default'...
[11:41:02] Starting 'sass'...

Fetching Sass Source Files...
   - resources\assets\sass\app.scss


Saving To...
   - public\css\app.css

[11:41:02] Finished 'default' after 323 ms
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: no writecb in Transform class
    at afterTransform (d:\..\..\..\node_modules\gulp-autoprefixer\node_modules\readable->stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:95:33)
    at Immediate.TransformState.afterTransform (d:\..\..\..\node_modules\gulp->autoprefixer\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:79:12)
    at Immediate.immediate._onImmediate (timers.js:435:18)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
```

I already deleted all my node_modules and installed them back again with no luck.

Anyone else having this problem?

Versions:

- Laravel Framework version 5.1.24 (LTS)
- Node: 4.2.2
- npm: 3.5.1
- gulp: 3.90

Comment: Seems it was an [gulp-autoprefixer issue](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-autoprefixer/issues/46). Perhaps this happens due to version of a package or node itself. Maybe you need some downgrade of `gulp-autoprefixer` package or smth like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seeing you're using 'Laravel' I can only assume you're using 'laravel-elixir'.
Due to recent changes in this package there are some compatibility problems with SASS.

You can always use a fixed version in your package.json file and set it to

```
  "dependencies": {
    "laravel-elixir": "3.4.2",
  }
```

instead of the default ^3.0.0, witch will auto update to the latest version.
After changing the version just re-run `npm update`

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Yes, this fixed it! Apparently laravel-elixir was updated to version 3.4.3 which caused this error. Thanks!

Comment: actually the current laravel-elixir version is at 4.0.4 which is a stable release , you SHOULD try updating your npm version with `npm install npm@latest -g`    and your node version check on [https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/] for your OS version install and update , also update global gulp with `npm install gulp@latest -g`  , this should resolve your issues